# how to set frame of UITableViewCell's AccessoryView without sub classing UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Whenever I try to set the frame of a `UITableViewCell's AccssoryView` it does not make any change to the original frame of the accessory view, however, I want to re-position the accessory view of  the default `UITableViewCell` without any sub-classing ? is that possible ?

I've tired `CGAffineTransformations` to make a mirror for the cell but it did not work.
Even subclassing `UITableViewCell` and setting the frame for `self.accessoryView.frame` in `layoutSubviews` has no effect too.

Answer (score 0):

first I try to get UITableView Cell subviews when `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;` and I got :

```
<UITableViewCellContentView: 0x1463e500; frame = (0 0; 320 44); gestureRecognizers =      <NSArray: 0x1463e340>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1463e4d0>>,
<UIButton: 0x1463d920; frame = (0 0; 14 14); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1463ddd0>>
```

it seems the button is UITableViewCell's accessoryView but it's origin are (0,0),so after that i try

```
for (UIView *view in cell.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        view.frame = CGRectMake(20, 0, 14, 14);
    }
}
```

and i got

```
<UIButton: 0x1463d920; frame = (20 0; 14 14); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1463ddd0>>
```

but the position of accessory is not changing..
I think that means UITableViewCell place accessoryView itself in the rightPosition .you can not re-position the accessoryView of the origin `UITableViewCell`.

Here is my research, If anybody find a way to do it or somehow i'm wrong about this, tell me .